# azureml.contrib.dataset vs azureml.data

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

Looks like AzureML Python SDK has two Dataset packages exposed over API:

1. [azureml.contrib.dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.tabulardataset?view=azure-ml-py)
2. [azureml.data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-contrib-dataset/azureml.contrib.dataset.tabulardataset?view=azure-ml-py)

The documentation doesn't clearly mention the difference or when should we use which one? But, it creates confusion for sure. For example, There are two Tabular Dataset classes exposed over API. And they have different APIs for different functions:

1. [azureml.data.TabularDataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.tabulardataset?view=azure-ml-py)
2. [azureml.contrib.dataset.TabularDataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-contrib-dataset/azureml.contrib.dataset.tabulardataset?view=azure-ml-py)

Any suggestion about when should I use which package will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/azureml-contrib-dataset/), `azureml.contrib.dataset` has been deprecated and `azureml.data` should be used instead:

> The azureml-contrib-dataset package has been deprecated and might not
> receive future updates and removed from the distribution altogether.
> Please use azureml-core instead.